# How to get qmgr list in WebSphere MQ cluster

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a repository queue manager say REPQMGR in a WebSphere MQ cluster. What mqsc command should i use on REPQMGR to get all the queue manager's list in the cluster. In specific i need to inquire a property value from all queue managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
runmqsc
DIS CLUSQMGR(*) CLUSTER(clusname) ALL
```

This command will show you all the QMgrs in the cluster.  You can also specify a particular attribute that you want to know about instead of using `ALL`.

If you are writing script, have a look at [SupportPac MO72](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMO72).  This is a version of runmqsc that a) can operate as a client; b) has a number of useful formatting options; and c) also managed CCDT files.

In particular, you can tell MO72 to return results on a single line rather than the standard runmqsc two-column format.  This means that a script can look for the object name and attribute name on the same output line rather than having to parse many lines for a single object.